# Сессиии в php и их виды

Tags: php, сессия

Как работают сессии в php? Почти везде где я читал написано что сессии должны закрываться вместе с закрытием страницы браузера, или по истечении временем неактивности, в том случае если окно браузера открыто. Но, существуют видимо некоторые виды сессий, которые не закрываются с закрытием браузера, потом что они живут и находятся в браузере, даже после его закрытия. Так-же я наткнулся на эту статью, которая говорит о том, что в браузере GoogleChrom, не закрываются сессионные куки.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10617954/chrome-doesnt-delete-session-cookies

**Вопрос:** Какие существуют виды сессий , причем тут сессионные куки, и как это всё работает. Как те сессии которые живут даже после закрытия браузера, идентифицируют пользователя?

**Пожалуйста, обратите внимание!**
 Мы нуждаемся в полном и четком ответе, возможно даже с примером. То есть, ответ в виде ссылки на какой-то источник, без самого полного ответа , не годится.

Comment: @FiR, это хорошо, что вы наткнулись на статью. А ответы вы прочитали?

Comment: @VenZell  Да, конечно, мы ответы в статье прочитали.

Comment: @VenZell  Вы наверное хотели спросить, почему мы задаём такой вопрос, когда на кукую-ту часть вопроса, сами же даём ответ. Если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Искусственный разум задает вопросы о_О

Comment: @FiR, пожалуйста, конкретизируйте вопрос. Желательно с примером. "Делаю то-то. Ожидаю то-то. Получается то-то. Почему так?" - примерно таким образом

Comment: @VenZell Если мы поменяем контекст нашего вопроса, он утратит свою ценность для нас. Попробуйте на него ответить, если у нас возникнут вопросы по поводу Вашего ответа, мы оставим комментарий под ним, для последующей корректировки. Приятного Вам дня.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть 1 вид сессий - сессии.

**Сессия** - набор данных на сервере привязанный к конкретному пользователю на Вашем сайте. Привязка пользователя к сессии происходит благодаря сессионной куке (cookie) которая по умолчанию носит название `PHPSESSID`. Для каждого пользователя генерируется такая кука (с названием `PHPSESSID`) с УНИКАЛЬНЫМ значением.

**Время жизни сессии.**

По умолчанию, сессия живет на сервере в течении 1440 секунд, после чего считается устаревшей и может быть удалена автоматически. Т.е. будут удалены все данные на сервере которые хранились в сессии пользователя. ([session.gc-maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime))

**Время жизни сессионной куки**

По умолчанию время жизни куки равно "0". Это значит что сессионная кука будет удалена как только пользователь закроет браузер. Если установить значение [session.cookie-lifetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) отличное от 0 то данные кука будет удалены спустя заданное время (значение устанавливается в секундах)

Сессионные данные пользователя доступны через суперглобальный массив $_SESSION.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за отзыв. Не могли бы вы еще более подробно описать, если это возможно? Если больше добавить нечего, тогда не ладно.