# Как защитить данные в куках?

Tags: php

Добра всем.) 
Нужно запомнить пользователя в куках. Но так что бы защитить данные.
Ну и естественно передавать их по страницам.
Вопрос? как это сделать?

Comment: какие именно данные? и от чего конкретно защитить?

Comment: Нужно от редактирования чужих данных. через свои. данные.
вот запрос UPDATE users SET name='boss',seurname='sos',sex='1',mygroup='wos',balls=10000,berd_year='1000',place='всегда',email='@@@шима@@@' WHERE id='id' LIMIT 1; если я там посталю любой id я испорчу чужие данные

Comment: Вы не должны давать возможности редактировать ID автора. Или, на худой конец, всегда проверять чтобы они совпадали.

Comment: `id` такой у вас в сессии должен хранится, а не в куках. А при редактировании информации связанной с автором (статей каких нибудь или постов) вы должны проверять, что их id также совпадают.

Comment: @ДимаПерильман при старте сессии на сервере, идентификатор сессии записывается в куку, чтобы дать браузеру понять, что это тот самый юзер. там столько символов, что подобрать случайно сложно. и ты должен брать идентификатор юзера не из кук, а из данных авторизованного пользователя.

Comment: Я бы порекомендовал еще почитать о csrf. Жаль тут обстоятельного ответа на эту тему нет.

Comment: я вообще в сессии все храню. Но сессия живет до выключения броузера)

Comment: @ДимаПерильман жизнь сессии настраивается. и вполне себе заводится посмотрев на PHPSESSID в куках

Comment: возможно вы путаете с `sessionStorage` в JS ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, а вики чем плоха? https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0

Comment: @Other слишком сухо, как обычно, и без практических примеров как  сделать, чтоб можно было взглянуть и поразбираться, а не делать очередной запрос о более детальном разборе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, гугл -> [хабр](https://habrahabr.ru/post/144406/), [ещё что-то](https://raz0r.name/articles/zashhita-ot-csrf/).

Comment: @ДимаПерильман короч. необходимо тебе посмотреть детально информацию по сессиям. Напр. при старте сессии юзера заводится файл на сервере `sess_dq0pglklабракадабра`, в которой инфа о его сессии, типа `UID|i:1;instance|O:2:"Db":10:{s:10:"`... вот этот `UID` торчит в куках у юзера, который дает понять, что вот эта сессия принадлежит вот этому юзеру. и когд юзер заходит на сайт - дергается кука и заводится сессия по UID опять. При запросах в БД ты должен id брать на основе его сессии, так сказать... + почитать о `csrf` что это и как реализовать. Тогда все эти запросы с "неверными" id - отпадут

Comment: Я пользую сессию, мне нужно увеличить время жизни сессии. на год. Как это сделать?

Comment: [session.gc_maxlifetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime), [session.cookie_lifetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime).

Comment: `мне нужно увеличить время жизни сессии. на год. Как это сделать?` -
 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/194912/191482, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/683014/191482, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/502099/191482 ....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Подскажи как восстановить сессию после выключения браузера. Я делаю вот так но что то не хватает  if (!isset($_COOKIE['sit'])) {
    session_start();
    setcookie('sit',session_id(),strtotime('10 year'));
}else {
    session_id($_COOKIE['sit']);
}

Answer (score 1):

Всё, что отправляется клиенту, уже заведомо будет расшифровано (не хакером, так браузером).

Поэтому отправлять можно либо то, что должно быть расшифровано, либо что-то типа ID сессии - сам ID ничего не стоит, а данные надёжно сохранены на сервере.

Comment: тоесть в куку заносить id сесии? А как ее получить? и как потом подставить?

Comment: @ДимаПерильман пхп сам об этом позаботится когда запустите сессию

Comment: @ДимаПерильман, почитайте основы: http://phpfaq.ru/sessions Вы запускаете сессию, пых генерирует сессию, помещает ID сессии в куки, Вы работаете с ней через `$_SESSION`. Повторный запрос восстанавливает сессию по полученному ID (если его подменят - ничего страшного, просто старая сессия умрёт, пых потом её сотрёт) и вуаля :)